# Golang brackets syntax explanation

Tags: go

I can't figure out what does these brackets do in this code:

```golang
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    v1 := router.Group("/v1")
    { // <- these brackets
        v1.POST("/login", loginEndpoint)
        v1.POST("/submit", submitEndpoint)
        v1.POST("/read", readEndpoint)
    } // <- and these

    v2 := router.Group("/v2")
    { // <- and these
        v2.POST("/login", loginEndpoint)
        v2.POST("/submit", submitEndpoint)
        v2.POST("/read", readEndpoint)
    } // <- and these

    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

Got this code from here: https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#grouping-routes
Can you explain this?

Comment: They define lexical scope. They're meaningless there, though, since there are no variables defined within those scopes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the lexical scope (as commented) does not scope anything, it is more a "coding style" here, as expressed in [`gin-gonic/gin` issue 108](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/108#issuecomment-53999693)

> I, personally, like to use the brackets because **it gives a sense of group, and makes the routes easier to read**.

```
// notify the "test" variable
test := r.Group("/", TestHandle())
{
    test.GET("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
        fmt.Printf("test")
        c.String(200, "ok")
    })
}
```

Comment: From my personal perspective - this type of scoping makes code more clumsy. But anyway, that's interesting to know about this.

Comment: @Andrii I agree. This is not a "style" you have to follow.

Comment: I agree with the comments. This is a _bad_ style, IMO. Always seek to reduce, not increase, indentation. Any added clarity is already present with newline, and the added confusion (as this very question demonstrates) increases cognitive burden.